# where are route matches processed in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

Working on a laravel project, here are some sample entries in the `/app/routes.php` file:

```
    Route::get('contact',             'StaticController@getContact');

    // Search page
    Route::get('search',              'StaticController@getSearch');

    // Configurator/selection tool
    Route::get('selection-tool',      'StaticController@getConfigurator');
```

I understand that what's being done is, an array of routes is being built, and then based on matching, the correct one is called.  My question is, where does that calling happen?  It's obvious the entire `routes.php` file is processed and the actual selection happens later.

Comment: Is it new project or already built one ?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.1.10/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php

Answer (score 0):

### 4.2:

The route matching happens in the [Router class from the Laravel framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php).

The part you are looking for is [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1015)

### 5.4

If anyone wants to know where it takes place in 5.4:

Matching still happens in the [Router class from the Laravel framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php).

[The specific part](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L502)